# Store objects in array using mongodb, node and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to build a messaging system for my school project. I have created a schema in mongodb that looks like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  messages: []
});
```

I want to store an object in the messages that looks something similar to this:

```
{
 from: 'fromUsername',
 to: 'toUsername',
 time: new Date(),
 msg: 'message is here'
}
```

I want to be able to store that in the schema under the messages array. Is there a way to push that to the shcema? Not sure how to approach this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use th `$push` operator to appends your object value in the message array.

An example of how to use $push for your userSchema

```
// How to update a user already created
var User = mongoose.model('User');

User.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $push: {messages : {  
        from: 'fromUsername',
        to: 'toUsername',  
        time: new Date(),  
        msg: 'message is here'}}
    })
```

Comment: Could you clarify where this code would be placed? I'm not sure how to use this particular piece of code or how to call this code from an angular front-end for instance. Thanks so much for your willingness to help!

Comment: You need to put this part of code in a route of your nodejs server (let the server make the request to the db and not the client). In the angular frontend you make a $http POST request to your server with your message object in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the schemas separately with the message schema embedded as part of the user document (as items within the messages array):

```
var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    from: String,
    to: String,
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    msg: String
})

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    messages: [messageSchema]
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

To add the given message to the messages array, follow the pattern:

```
// retrieve user model
var User = mongoose.model('User');

// create user instance
var user = new User({
    firstName: 'Alice',
    lastName: 'Bob'
});

// create a message
user.messages.push({
    from: 'fromUsername',
    to: 'toUsername',
    msg: 'message is here'
});
```

You have an option to exclude the time field since you would have defined its default value when you persist your model.

```
user.save(function (err, user) {
    if (!err) console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply! I'm fairly new to the mean stack. I'm having trouble visualizing how this is handled within the server. Would the to and from users both get their messages added to their messages array? So if user a sends to user b, would both user a and user b have the message in the `messages: [messageSchema]`? Thanks!